# Why is Keycloak not functioning properly in my one Master and one worker Kubernetes cluster using Rook?

Tags: kubernetes

Rook Problem | PVC

Currently, Rook doesn't seem to be working properly, but it's important to note that I only have one Master and one worker, which is intended for testing purposes.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
kubectl create -f crds.yaml -f common.yaml -f operator.yaml
kubectl create -f cluster.yaml
```

```
│ NAMESPACE↑     NAME                                               PF   READY  RESTARTS STATUS IP      NODE│
│ default        keycloak-0                                         ●    0/1    0 Init:0/2  Pending  worker1│
│ default        keycloak-postgresql-0                              ●    0/0    0 Pending   Pending  n/a    │
│ rook-ceph      csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-84cc595b78-js849      ●    5/5    0 Running   *.*.*.*  master │
│ rook-ceph      csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-84cc595b78-ssqtr      ●    5/5    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      csi-cephfsplugin-rpg29                             ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  master │
│ rook-ceph      csi-cephfsplugin-zx49b                             ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      csi-rbdplugin-fcdc2                                ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      csi-rbdplugin-mqtfr                                ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  master │
│ rook-ceph      csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-6f6b6b8cd6-9gnr5         ●    5/5    0 Running   *.*.*.*  master │
│ rook-ceph      csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-6f6b6b8cd6-ddxgh         ●    5/5    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-crashcollector-worker1-76cbf45f6d-8j62n  ●    1/1    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-mgr-a-5cc5d765cc-ghzl7                   ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-mon-a-6579b556bc-r28sm                   ●    2/2    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-operator-8559cbbf59-x8hlk                ●    1/1    0 Running   *.*.*.*  worker1│
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-osd-prepare-master-4c9fp                 ●    0/1    0 Completed *.*.*.*  master │
│ rook-ceph      rook-ceph-osd-prepare-worker1-6r85f                ●    0/1    0 Completed *.*.*.*  worker1│
```

While my root pods appear to be fine, I'm experiencing issues with Keycloak not functioning correctly. Here's the relevant event information:

```
│   Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message
│   Warning  FailedScheduling  94s (x2 over 7m4s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..     │
```

Additionally, in the PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC), I encountered the following event:

````
│
│ Events:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│   Type    Reason         Age                    From                         Message                                                                                                                                                     │
│   ----    ------         ----                   ----                         -------                                                                                                                                                     │
│   Normal  FailedBinding  2m50s (x26 over 9m2s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set  ```
````